# Str implemented in class not used

Tags: python

Let us assume I have a class which implements the **str**() function. When I now put an object of this class into a dictionary and use str() of the dictionary, it does not use this function! What did I do wrong?

```
class test(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return("I am a dork")
a = test()
print(a)
X = {0:a}
print(str(tuple(sorted(X.items()))))
```

which returns:

```
I am a dork
((0, <__main__.test object at 0x7fe5204ddbe0>),)
```

Obviously, the goal would be to have

```
((0, 'I am a dork'),)
```

Comment: Define `__repr__` as well

Comment: When you convert a container like tuple to a string, it gets the `repr`esentation of the elements it contains.

Answer (score 3):

Containers in Python show *representations*, not string conversions. You need to implement [`object.__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) to influence the object representation.

Note that `__str__` and `__repr__` play different roles; the representation is there for debugging purposes, the `__str__` string output for presentation. If `__str__` is missing, `__repr__` will be used, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
class test(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return("I am a dork")
    def __repr__(self):
        return("I am a dork too")
```

Here **repr** [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)